# Creating pandas dataframe from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have written the python following code:

```
# Data to be formatted into pandas data frame: PDYN, DST, BYIMF, BZIMF, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5, W6.

# Import the necessary modules
import numpy as np
import datetime as dtm
import pandas as pd
import spacepy
import spacepy.time as spt
import spacepy.omni as spo

# Initial time: 2003-10-29T06:00:00 (DST = -10nT)
# Final time: 2003-10-30T17:00:00 (DST = -97nT)

# Extract the data during time interval using spacepy

start_time = dtm.datetime(2003, 10, 29, 6)                  # Initial time
end_time = dtm.datetime(2003, 10, 30, 17)               # Final time
dt = dtm.timedelta(hours = 1)                               # Time delta
ticks = spt.tickrange(start_time, end_time, dt, 'UTC')      # Range for time ticks
time_data = spo.get_omni(ticks)                                 # Create data dictionary

# Create data frame using Pandas
d = {'Time Stamp': time_data['ticks'], 'PDYN': time_data['Pdyn'], 'DST': time_data['Dst'], 'BYIMF': time_data['ByIMF'], 'BZIMF': time_data['BzIMF'], 'W1': time_data['W'][0], 'W2': time_data['W'][1], 'W3': time_data['W'][2], 'W4': time_data['W'][3], 'W5': time_data['W'][4], 'W6': time_data['W'][5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

I have extracted data from spacepy, and I am trying to create a pandas data frame representing the parameters that I need. As you can see, the variable `time_data` is a dictionary. When I go to create the data frame, I continue to get the following error:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length.
```

In formatting the dictionary, the key `W` corresponds to an array that is composed of 6 other arrays which correspond to the parameters `W1`-`W6`, respectively. For these, I am trying to index the `W` array inside the dictionary. Is there a better way to do this? In trying to diagnose the problem, I just wanted to see if it would produce a data frame for at least one of the parameters. With this, I had

```
# Import the necessary modules
import numpy as np
import datetime as dtm
import pandas as pd
import spacepy
import spacepy.time as spt
import spacepy.omni as spo

# Initial time: 2003-10-29T06:00:00 (DST = -10nT)
# Final time: 2003-10-30T17:00:00 (DST = -97nT)

# Extract the data during time interval using spacepy

start_time = dtm.datetime(2003, 10, 29, 6)                  # Initial time
end_time = dtm.datetime(2003, 10, 30, 17)               # Final time
dt = dtm.timedelta(hours = 1)                               # Time delta
ticks = spt.tickrange(start_time, end_time, dt, 'UTC')      # Range for time ticks
time_data = spo.get_omni(ticks)                                 # Create data dictionary

# Create data frame using Pandas
d = {'Time Stamp': time_data['ticks']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

With this I get two errors:

```
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 33
```

and

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 36, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), indices imply (36, 1)
```

Does anyone have any solutions? Thank you.

Comment: I think this thread can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925771/valueerror-arrays-must-all-be-same-length-while-converting-dictionary-to-data-f

Comment: Provide output of `print(d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution was to pass a tuple that contains a slice when indexing the values assigned to the `W` key. This was necessary because each value assigned to the `W` key was an array at each time stamp. These arrays are made of 6 elements, each one corresponding to some parameters `W1`-`W6`. Slicing was necessary in order to extract the values from the array that corresponded to those parameters. Here is some code that works.

```
# Data to be formatted into pandas data frame: PDYN, DST, BYIMF, BZIMF, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5, W6.

# Import the necessary modules
import numpy as np
import datetime as dtm
import pandas as pd
import json
import spacepy
import spacepy.time as spt
import spacepy.omni as spo
#import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()

# Initial time: 2003-10-29T06:00:00 (DST = -10nT)
# Final time: 2003-10-30T17:00:00 (DST = -97nT)

# Extract the data during time interval using spacepy
start_time = dtm.datetime(2003, 10, 29, 6)                      # Initial time
end_time = dtm.datetime(2003, 10, 30, 17)                       # Final time
dt = dtm.timedelta(hours = 1)                                   # Time delta
ticks = spt.tickrange(start_time, end_time, dt, 'UTC')          # Range for time ticks
time_data = spo.get_omni(ticks)                                 # Create data dictionary

# Equate the index with the hour
datetime_series = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start = start_time, end = end_time, freq = 'h'))
# Create time dependent data frame using Pandas
d ={'Date, Time': datetime_series, 'PDYN': time_data['Pdyn'], 'DST': time_data['Dst'],'BYIMF': time_data['ByIMF'], 'BZIMF': time_data['BzIMF'], 'W1': time_data['W'][:,0], 'W2': time_data['W'][:,1], 'W3': time_data['W'][:,2], 'W4': time_data['W'][:,3], 'W5': time_data['W'][:,4], 'W6': time_data['W'][:,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```